# How do you deserialize json into a C# object that has "@" at the beginning of the property names?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am having trouble deserializing json I have that has an `@` symbol at the beginning of a lot of the property names.  It is a lot of json so I don't know if just removing all `@` from the json is safe or if I would lose some valuable information in the values associated with properties.

I tried using a `[JsonProperty("@fontName")]`, for example, but that didn't work (the C# object did not adopt the value I see in the JSON; it was `null` instead).

```
internal static RootObject MyMethod(string json)
{
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    return rootObject;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the json I'm dealing with:

```
{
  "document": {
    "page": [
      {
        "@index": "0",
        "row": [
          {
            "column": [
              {
                "text": ""
              },
              {
                "text": {
                  "@fontName": "Times New Roman",
                  "@fontSize": "8.0",
                  "@x": "133",
                  "@y": "14",
                  "@width": "71",
                  "@height": "8",
                  "#text": "FINAL STATEMENT"
                }
...
```

Here is an example of what I want to deserialize into:

```
public class Column
{
    [JsonProperty("@fontName")]
    public string fontName { get; set; }
    public object text { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public List<Column> column { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public string index { get; set; }
    public List<Row> row { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public List<Page> page { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Document document { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you ?

Comment: What does _that didn't work_ mean? What happened exactly? Also as @mybirthname hints at in the answer below, you're going to need to come up with a way to make `Text` hold a complex type or a string.

Comment: @mybirthname, I will be trying this out tonight or tomorrow and will let you know.  It is similar to the approach I tried above, and that didn't work, but I'll try to see if I missed something.

@AndrewWhitaker, it didn't work means that when I get the C# object back, the information I expected to be held in that property was `null` instead.  The deserialization (as a black-box) did not work in the sense that my input did not produce the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you miss one of your properties `index` property of your `Page` object.

Write it this way `[JsonProperty(PropertyName ="@index")]` it is better to understand.  Also we don't see the definition of `fontName`, `fontSize`, `x`, `y` and so on, in separate `Text` class. For some reason you wrote it as just as object.

```
public class Text
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="@fontName")]
    public string FontName {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="@fontSize")]
    public string FontSize {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="#text")]
    public string TextResult{get; set;}

    //other objects
}

public class Column
{
    public List<Text> text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This approach makes sense.  I will try this again soon.  Just wanted to mention that this is exactly what I tried already with the `fontName` property.  The reason I didn't put the `JsonProperty` decorator/attribute on the rest of the properties is pure laziness.  I didn't want to put those all on until I proved to myself that that's what I needed to do.  Since it didn't work for `fontName`, I took that to mean that it wouldn't work for the rest.